# Laravel filter with query builder retrieving wrong data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The query is retrieving wrong data, must retrieve only `departamento` **not null**. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
$banca = Banca::with(['trabalho.membrobanca.departamento' => function($query) use ($d) {
    $query->where('id', $d);
}])->get();

$banca = collect($banca)
    ->unique('trabalho_id')
    ->values()
    ->all();
```

[image: Result this]

The diagram with relationship.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45606389/5013099

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel has() function. It will return return **Banca** where **departamento** is not null

```
$banca = Banca::with(['trabalho.membrobanca.departamento' => function($query) use ($d) {
    $query->where('id', $d);
}])

// has function will return banca if banca has non-null departamento
->has('trabalho.membrobanca.departamento')

->get();
```

Check this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Close enough, I'll go with your answer.

Comment: You may never need that `$query->where('id', $d)` since you have checked it's child existence via `has`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the filter on the `memrobanca` table and filter on null values.

```
$banca = Banca::with([
        'trabalho.membrobanca' => function($query) use ($d) {
            $query->where('departamento_id', $d)
                ->whereNotNull('departamento_id')
                ->with('departamento');
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: The scoped query inside `with` method is `Banca` query builder (CMIIW). So, how do you know that `Banca` has `departamento_id` column?

Comment: I know there is a `departemento_id` because I can see it in the result set you posted in your question.

Comment: The `Banca` has `trabalho_id` and in the table `Trabalho` has `membrobanca_id` and in the table `MembroBanca` has the `departamento_id`